# Any way to play audio file for windows desktop application in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

I'm new to flutter and making a desktop application with flutter. Now I need to load and play audio files but found that the audio player packages don't support desktop software in windows. So if there is any way to play audio file for windows desktop software using flutter, then please give me an example.

Note: After searching a bit I found this ([flutter_audio_desktop](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_desktop/install)) but unfortunately it's status is "DISCONTINUED".

Comment: any update on this?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh use just audio - https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio. Windows support is enabled by adding an additional dependency to your pubspec.yaml alongside just_audio. Follow the readme section for details.

Answer (score 0):

just_audio plugin has a support for windows as well. You can use that plugin to play audio file.
There is another plugin named audioplayers which also has windows support in the prelease version 1.0.0-rc.1.

Answer (score 0):

[Dart VLC](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_vlc) is also a good option to play audio files for flutter desktop application. This package can play both audio and video files.